# Send email using smtp but operation timed out using ZOHO

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp, zoho

```
Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(abc@zoho.com,abc123)
Smtp_Server.Port = 465
Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.zoho.com"
e_mail = New MailMessage()
e_mail.From = New MailAddress(abc@zoho.com)
e_mail.To.Add("david@hotmail.com")
e_mail.Subject = "Testing"
e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
Return True
```

Now I trying to send email to other person but the error show me the operation timed out, when using ZOHO to send. And I got find the solution but still fail to send. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 7):

Try to use PORT : 587

```
Smtp_Server.Port = 587
```